# nginx alternative index not working

Tags: php, nginx

Trying to get login.php or /login to be the index page when going to a subdomain but all I get is a blank page.

Config below:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.domain.org;

    root   /var/www/html/domain.org/public;
    index login login.php index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~* \.(css|js|png|woff2|woff|ttf|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {}

    location = / {
      index login.php;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.php login;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri.php;
    }

    error_page 404 404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.domain.org;

    root   /var/www/html/domain.org/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~* \.(css|js|png|woff2|woff|ttf|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {}

    location / {
      index login.php;
    }

    error_page 404 404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

If still not working try add logging to server directive and see what's going wrong:

```
error_log /var/www/html/domain.org/public/nginx-error.log;
access_log /var/www/html/domain.org/public/nginx-access.log;
```

Comment: location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.php login;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri.php;
    } - you took this out